# List all my working processes in Linux

Tags: linux, process

`pgrep` is the command used to return a process ID.  Now I would like to see the process ID of my working processes rather than giving a single process — how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean `ps`?

Comment: yeah you r right

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question rather than the title... try:

```
ps -a
```